# how to use toolbar(humburger icon) as backstack navigation

Tags: android

I have to navigate fragment back to mainactivity and if i have more than one fragment in activity, then i need navigate one by one back using toolbar(humburger icon).

[image]

Comment: So you want to change hamburger icon to back arrow icon if more than one fragment is there ? is that right

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment hosting the toolbar, call the activity backpress:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

To change the icon to back arrow, in your fragment:

```
        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // Loading the arrow drawable.
            final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha); // should work
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }
```

Comment: thanks ji..how to change back arrow if i'm in fragement